# Stop related entities being loaded automatically in Sqlite in-memory dB using Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, sqlite, entity-framework-core, in-memory-database

I'm using EF Core (v1.1.3) and C#.

In my unit tests I create a sqlite in-memory database using the code-first db model, and then populate it with some test data. However when loading a list of entities from the dB, then related entities are getting populated, despite no '.Include' being used.

If I use the same model to create an actual on-disk database and the do the same load, then the related entities only get loaded if I use an `.Include`.

Is this a bug in the sqlite in-memory implementation (v1.1.0), or am I missing something?

I have already checked that there is nothing being tracked in the database, and obviously I can't dispose the context and renew it because of it being in-memory, and I'm limited to this version of EF & Sqlite currently, due to legacy reasons.

Obviously I'd prefer to have an in-memory option for unit tests rather than start creating on-disk tests, for the performance.

Comment: _"...and obviously I can't dispose the context and renew it because of it being in-memory..."_ - why not?

Comment: Please post [mcve] how you are creating your context for _"...However when loading a list of entities from the dB, then related entities are getting populated, despite no '.Include' being used..."_

Comment: @MickeyD. I cant dispose of the context, because as soon as you do, all content will be lost ! I

Comment: After googling and reading [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50634745/585968), EF Core did not introduce automatic Lazy Loading (which would have explained your issue) until [**EF Core 2.1**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data#lazy-loading).  Considering you are using EFC v1.1x, you should only have _eager_ and _explcit_ at your disposal.  Not sure what is causing the issue sadly

Comment: _"I `cant dispose` of the `context`, because as soon as you do, all content will be `lost` !"_ - [Incorrect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/testing/sqlite).  Perhaps you are thinking about the _connection_? Ensure you are using `DbContextOptionsBuilder`

Comment: Did you found solution? I have the exact same problem with EF Core 3.1

Comment: I've seen the same thing in EF Core on .NET 5

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same problem.

What you need to do is set the state of the entity that you have created for the test to `Detatched`. Then, when you try to read the entity again, EF will fetch it from DB.

Write this line after you create new entity:

```
dbContext.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Detached;
```