# EF Core one-to-many relationships has No value

Tags: c#

**Connecter.cs**

```
public virtual DbSet<Guild> Guild { get; set; }
public virtual DbSet<Role> Role { get; set; }
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Guild>(entity => {
        entity.HasKey(e => e.Gid)
            .HasName("PRIMARY");
        entity.HasIndex(e => e.Gid)
            .HasName("gid_UNIQUE")
            .IsUnique();
        entity.Property(e => e.Gid)
            .HasColumnName("gid")
            .HasColumnType("bigint(20) unsigned");
    });
    modelBuilder.Entity<Role>(entity => {
        entity.HasKey(e => e.Gid);

        entity.HasIndex(e => e.Gid)
            .HasName("gid");

        entity.Property(e => e.Gid)
            .HasColumnName("gid")
            .HasColumnType("bigint(20) unsigned");
        entity.HasOne(d => d.Guild)
            .WithMany(p => p.Role)
            .HasForeignKey(d => d.Gid)
            .HasConstraintName("role_ibfk_1");
    });
}
```

**Guild.cs**

```
public Guild() // ef core auto create
{
    Role = new HashSet<Role>();
}

public ulong Gid { get; set; }
[ForeignKey("Gid")]
public virtual ICollection<Role> Role { get; set; }
```

**Role.cs**

```
public ulong Gid { get; set; }
public virtual Guild Guild { get; set; }
```

**Main.cs**

```
public static void Main(string[] args) 
{
    var context = new Connector();
    var single = context.Guild.Single(e => e.Gid == 442018515965313024);
    Trace.WriteLine(single.Role.Count); // Result : 0
}
```

Clearly, there are values ​​corresponding to "Gid" in schemas (Guild, Role).
However, there is no value in the relationship. Did I do something wrong?

Comment: Does it work when you add `Include(it => it.Role)` to your query?

Comment: Well the value comes out well, but must I use Include? I want to use it more comfortably

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Entity Framework Core - Lazy Loading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40122162/entity-framework-core-lazy-loading)

Comment: I think it's right, thanks