# Can I use Lazy Loading in EF Core in NetStandard?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core, .net-standard

We are converting our data class library from .Net Framework to .Net Standard 2.0 so we can continue to use it in our old Framework projects but also utilize it in our new .Net Core projects.

Things are generally working well, but it does not use the Lazy Loading on which we depended in the Framework project, e.g. when I load an EmployeeIndexItem with an IndexItem, it does not get the Index Item:

```
[Table( "EmployeeIndexItem", Schema = "Core" )]
    public class EmployeeIndexItem
    {
        public Guid EmployeeIndexItemId { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid();

        public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
        public Guid IndexItemId { get; set; }
        public virtual IndexItem IndexItem { get; set; }
    }
```

I have found the [EntityFrameworkCore.Proxies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/lazy) documentation, but "Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Proxies 6.0.4 is not compatible with netstandard2.0"

Is there a way to get the Lazy Loading to work in NetStandard?  Or should I bite the bullet and do the necessary Includes?

Comment: You must take the package that's compatible with your EF version.

Comment: @GertArnold - to which package are you referring?  EntityFrameworkCore.Proxies?  I see there is an Arch.EntityFrameworkCore (https://www.nuget.org/packages/Arch.EntityFrameworkCore/2.1.15) but they seem very shady.

Comment: Well, which EF version do you have?

Comment: have you checked this link yet
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40122162/entity-framework-core-lazy-loading

Comment: @GertArnold - thank you!  If you want to submit an answer I will select it.  I did not realize that we were using the 3.1 version of EFCore, and thus could use the matching version of EFCore.Proxies.  Thank you!!